# SQL DWH create new foreign logic

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, star-schema

for example, I have **orderitems** table where I have columns:

- id int PK
- cost decimal(10,4)
- quantity int
- product_name varchar(100)
- sku varchar(100)

I want to move out distinct concatenated product_name and sku values to separate table. To have smth like this:
table **variants**:

- id identity(1,1) PK
- variant_name varchar(200)

And in the final I want to have this table **orderitems_fact**:

- id int PK
- variant_name_id int FK reference to **variants**
- cost decimal(10,4)
- quantity int

I tried to populate variants table like this:

```
insert into variants
(variant_name )
select distinct 
product_name||'-'||sku as variant_name 
from orderitems
```

and then when populating orderitems_fact I did this:

```
insert into orderitems_fact 
(id, variant_name_id, cost, quantity )
select 
o.id,
v.id as variant_name_id 
o.cost,
o.quantity 
from orderitems o
join variants v on o.product_name||'-'||o.sku = v.variant_name
```

so in the end I got expected table.

So the question, is this approach correct? Are there any others possibilities or technics ?

Comment: “Is this approach correct?” - if it gives the correct result then yes. “Are there any others possibilities or technics ?” - this is too broad a question; if you have a specific issue with your current solution then please update your question to explain what that issue is and provide any appropriate supporting information